# cannot access javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaDelete class file for javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaDelete not found

Tags: java, hibernate

I am learning Hibernate. I want to connect SQL server. I wrote this code and I receive an exception

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
        .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
        .addAnnotatedClass(Car.class)
        .buildSessionFactory();

Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

try {
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<Car> cars =  session.createQuery("from cars").getResultList();

    for (Car car : cars) {
        System.out.println(car.getCars_name());
    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
} finally {
    factory.close();
}
```

> cannot access javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaDelete
> class file for javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaDelete not found

Answer (score 0):

I thought dependency was missing :-

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```